# How can I shorten this Java code?

Tags: java

```
/* This program sorts out name in orders from
their first alphabetical orders .*/

package nameorder;

public class NameOrder {

    public static void sayName(String a, String s, String d){
        System.out.println("Name By Alphabetical Order: \n1."+a+"\n"+"2."+s+"\n3."+d+"\n");

    }

    public static void stringOrder(String a ,String s ,String d){
        int i= a.compareTo(s) ;
        int j= a.compareTo(d) ;
        int k= d.compareTo(s) ;
        int l= d.compareTo(a) ;
        String first="";
        String second="";
        String third="";
            if(i<0&&j<0){
                first=a;
                    if(k>0&&l>0){
                        third = d;
                        second = s;
                    }else{
                        second = d;
                        third = s;
                    }
            }else if(i>0&&j>0){
                third=a;
                    if(k<0&&l<0){
                        first = d;
                        second = s;
                    }else{
                        second = s;
                        first = d;
                    }
            }else{
                second=a;
                    if(k<0&&l<0){
                        first = d;
                        third = s;
                    }else{
                        first = s;
                        third = d;
                    }
            }
        sayName(first,second,third);    
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a ="C";
        String s ="a";
        String d ="h";
        stringOrder(a.toUpperCase(),s.toUpperCase(),d.toUpperCase()); 
    }

}
```

I'm just wondering if I'm doing this right or there is a better shorter version for this?

Comment: [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: [_"Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?"_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question), also this is more a code review request, which are off-topic here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056178/java-sorting-an-string-array-by-a-substring-of-characters this may help

Comment: i havent learned until there yet but it gave me a clear picture of what im going to expect further on my studies thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From just the perspective of "sorting three strings", you could just need to do three comparisons and lose all those temp variables.

```
public static void stringOrder(String a, String s, String d) {
    String tmp;

    if (a.compareTo(s) > 0) {
        tmp = a;
        a = s;
        s = tmp;
    }

    if (a.compareTo(d) > 0) {
        tmp = a;
        a = d;
        d = tmp;
    }

    if (s.compareTo(d) > 0) {
        tmp = s;
        s = d;
        d = tmp;
    }

    sayName(a, s, d);
}
```

But from a maintainability perspective, just use the facilities built into Java to sort multiple strings at a time:

```
public static void stringOrder(String a, String s, String d) {
    String [] arr = {a, s, d};
    java.util.ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(arr));
    java.util.Collections.sort(list);
    sayName(list.get(0), list.get(1), list.get(2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used Collections.List here so that your code is more dynamic, allowing for any
amount of strings to be ordered. With yours, you hard-coded that 3 strings would be entered. Here, you can enter as many strings as you'd like within the main function.

The Collections.Sort method will sort your list in the most efficient way. Whenever you can, use methods made by the guys at Java, as they've spent years optimizing these functions.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    // Create a collection to store the strings in
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Add the strings to the Collection
    list.add("C");
    list.add("A");
    list.add("H");

    // Use the Collections library to sort the strings for you, by their
    // defined ordering
    Collections.sort(list);

    // Print the ordered strings
    System.out.println("Names By Alphabetical Order: ");
    for(String string: list){
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}
```